# vee-validate: Is it possible to change the fields-bag-name without changing the current name?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

So I want to adapt the Autofill naming for Birthdays. However, this leads to several problems. Now I need to find out if I can force vee-validate to change the name of the field.

To understand it better. This is how it currently looks like:

```
<select
    v-model="day"
    id="day"
    name="day"
    :class="{'invalid' : errors.has('day')}"
    v-validate="'required|excluded:0'"
>
    <option
        :disabled="true"
        value="0"
        v-text="trans('food.Day')"
    />
    <option
        v-for="n in 31"
        :key="n"
        :value="n"
        v-text="n"
    />
</select>

<span
    class="bar"
    :class="{'invalid' : errors.has('day')}"
/>
```

The name for the select field is "day". 
However, according to [this](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fe-autocomplete-bday), it should be named: **"bday-day".**

Since I'm using vee-validate, this leads to a rename of the field name to "bday-day". Now `errors.has('day')}` won't work anymore.

But even if I change this to `errors.has('bday-day')`, I cannot use my internal watcher for changes in values. I get the error:

> Failed watching path: "bday-day" Watcher only accepts simple dot-delimited paths. For full control, use a function instead.

This is because I have to force the same name of the v-model name and vee-validate name. `v-model="bday-day"` cannot work.

To make it short. My end goal is something like this:

```
<select
    v-model="day"
    id="day"
    name="bday-day"
    :class="{'invalid' : errors.has('day')}"
    v-validate="{required: true, excluded: 0, name: 'day'}"
>
    <option
        :disabled="true"
        value="0"
        v-text="trans('food.Day')"
    />
    <option
        v-for="n in 31"
        :key="n"
        :value="n"
        v-text="n"
    />
</select>

<span
    class="bar"
    :class="{'invalid' : errors.has('day')}"
/>
```

I would use the `name="bday-day"` for autofill, but I would set the field name for vee validate to `name: 'day'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Use the `data-vv-name` attribute

Vee-validate has you covered and you can setup the attribute `data-vv-name` to achieve precisely this:

```
<select
    v-model="day"
    id="day"
    name="bday-day"
    :class="{'invalid' : errors.has('day')}"
    v-validate="'required|excluded:0'"
    data-vv-name="day"
>
```

Now the `errors` and `fields` members provided by `vee-validate` will have a `day` entry, instead of using the input name `bday-day`. Thus, if you have a watcher on `errors.day`, you won't have that nasty problem with the `bday-day` watching path.

Answer (score 1):

With VeeValidate v3, you have two relevant options you can pass to `ValidationProvider`, `name` and `vid`.

[VeeValidate's docs specify that](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/api/validation-provider.html#props):

`name` specifies a field name to be used in error messages.

`vid` is an identifier used for target/cross-field based rules.

From my tests though, `vid` is also used as the key for `fields` and `errors` in the `ValidationObserver` if provided, and if not, it falls back to `name`.

As a result, **if you have multiple of the same fields in one form, and you're looking to have a unique key name (so that they don't clash and break), then use `name` purely just for the field name in error messages, and `vid` to provide a unique ID to be used by `ValidationObserver` in the `fields` and `errors` objects.** For example:

```
<ValidationProvider
  name="hours" // used for error messages
  :vid="hours-${unique-part}" // unique key to stop clashes
  rules="required"
  v-slot="{ errors }"
>...</ValidationProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **VeeValidate v3**, you can set "name" attribute for the `ValidationProvider`

```
<ValidationProvider name="day" rules="required|excluded:0" v-slot="{ errors }">
```